# is there a way on how to allow the only user who uses a specified email to log into the support console

Tags: php, mysql

I am thinking of a way on how to allow the only user who uses a specified email to log into the support console. I have no idea, is this even possible?

Comment: What is Support Console ? Is it a Page or what ? You can add condition whether the user with specific email can go to support console else redirect it to main page.

Comment: yes ..its a page

Comment: of course it is possible. It is essentially only slightly different to a conventional login  - the user still needs to know email & pwd but only a single email address will be permitted - which can be done either by hardcoding(poor) or by an additional field in the user table that signifies that user is permitted to login

Comment: A better design would be to use roles rather than a fixed single user account. Then you can have more than one support user if you need to. E.g all users with "support" role can log into support console. If that's only one user right now then that's fine. But if you need more in future, or you need to change who it is, then you have some flexibility without needing to change the application itself.

Comment: Is this PhpMyAdmin?